# Taking data from one activity and storing it in another

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to build a very simple App in Android Studio to practice using Intents to send data from one activity to another. On my Main Activity I have a "Total" TextView and a button. When I click the button, it takes me to a AddNumber Activity where I can type in an integer and press a button. This then takes me back to the Main Activity and adds that integer to the total, updating the TextView. I want to be able to do this multiple times while I've got the app open so the total keeps going up.

I have tried using a ViewModel to store the information so it doesn't get reset every time the Main Activity onCreate method is run. However, every time I do this, it works once (e.g. if I add a 7 in my AddNumber Activity, the Main Activity total goes to 7). However, when I try again, the ViewModel seems to get reset so doesn't remember the 7 that I put in initially, so if I put in an 8, the total on the MainActivity just gets set to 8, rather than 15. Am I making a mistake somewhere that is causing the ViewModel to reset? I understood that ViewModels were a way of storing data while the app is open, but I can't seem to make it work.

Thanks so much!

**MainActivity.java code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView totalTextView;
MainActivityViewModel viewModel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    totalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTextView);
    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
    totalTextView.setText(Integer.toString(viewModel.total));
    getSetIncomingIntent();
}

public void addNumber(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddNumber.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void getSetIncomingIntent() {
    Intent incomingIntent = getIntent();
    if (incomingIntent.hasExtra("value")) {
        viewModel.newValue = incomingIntent.getIntExtra("value",0);
        viewModel.addNumber();
        totalTextView.setText(Integer.toString(viewModel.total));
    }
}
```

}

**MainActivityViewModel.java code:**

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {

    int total = 0;
    int newValue;
    public void addNumber() {
        total = total + newValue;
    }
}
```

**AddNumber.java code:**

```
public class AddNumber extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText numberEditText;
    int value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_number);
        numberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberEditText);
    }

    public void addNumber(View view){
        value = Integer.parseInt(numberEditText.getText().toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("value", value);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> When I click the button, it takes me to a AddNumber Activity where I can type in an integer and press a button. **This then takes me back to the Main Activity** and adds that integer to the total, updating the TextView.

This is not what is happening. First you create a *new* `AddNumber` activity.

```
public void addNumber(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddNumber.class);
    startActivity(intent); // This launches a new AddNumber Activity
}
```

And then here you are creating a *new* `MainActivity` instance.

```
public void addNumber(View view){
    value = Integer.parseInt(numberEditText.getText().toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("value", value);
    startActivity(intent); // This launches a new MainActivity
}
```

So you're basically building a giant stack of MainActivity / AddNumber instances.
You need to start `AddNumber` with `startActivityForResult` and then handle that in `MainActivity`. Then you will be working with the original `MainActivity` and the original ViewModel and you will be able to update it.

Please refer to [the documentation on starting an Activity for result](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Hope that helps!